# Angularjs resize dynamically iframe height

Tags: jquery, angularjs, iframe, angularjs-directive

In my case, I used an iframe and I need that its height is automatically calculated based on its content.

My code looks like this

```
<iframe id='iframe' width='100%' height='600px' src='http://test.com' />
```

How do I set the iframe content height through my controller or directive?

Can anyone help me? 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I think that what you want is to define a directive like iframeSetDimentionsOnload and set the height there. I will give you in example in a few minutes.

Your iframeSetDimensionsOnload directive:

```
yourApp.directive('iframeSetDimensionsOnload', [function(){

 return {

  restrict: 'A',

  link: function(scope, element, attrs){
    element.on('load', function(){

        /* Set the dimensions here, 
           I think that you were trying to do something like this: */

           var iFrameHeight = 

           element[0].contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
           var iFrameWidth = '100%';
           element.css('width', iFrameWidth);
           element.css('height', iFrameHeight);
      })
   }
 }
}])
```

Use it like this:

```
<iframe iframe-set-dimensions-onload src='http://test.com' />
```